# Position not showing in category sorting dropdown

Tags: magento2, category, sorting

I have a problem with the sort order of products in the categories:

The Position option is not showing in the dropdown as you can see in the screenshot.
[image]

In the Magento backend the position is selected as filterable.

As you can see in the screenshot:
[image]

Is there a bug in magento which disables this?